# Two Path Test for finding limit.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Does the following limit exist?

$ f(x,y) = \frac{2x^{2}y}{x^4 + y^2}$

as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$

Why is it that along the path $y = kx$ the limit is zero and along $y = kx^2$ It is clearly non existent. 
What curves then should be preferred as valid curves to test limit of any multivariable function, and also say, if the limit had existed along $y = kx^2$
then how do we know that the function would have a limit on ALL other paths too?

Comment: You already have an answer to your problem: since there are two different behaviours on two different curves through the origin, the limit does not exist. In general, the behaviour on a single path tells nothing about the behaviour on different paths.

Comment: Then when do I stop checking my answer for different paths?

Comment: what jack is trying to say is now that you have got that the limit is 0 along one path and non existent along another you can stop. This is enough to conclude that the limit does not exist

Comment: Once it looks to you that the limit is some number $L$, you prove that the limit really is $L$ through some inequality that accounts only for the distance of $(x,y)$ from the origin (*any* distance would do the job). A very common trick is to switch to polar coordinates.

Comment: Oh you mean using the classic definition of limit using delta and epsilon ,Jack?

Comment: @ShubhamTripathi: yes, exactly.

Comment: O.K.  then, thank you very much.