# Evaluate: $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$$

Intuitively the limit is $0$ as the numerator goes faster to $0$

I have tried the squeeze theorem but did not manage, can I take the absolute value of the function and the try the squeeze theorem? or because it have alternating signs I can (x^3+y^3)?

Comment: Squeeze theorem indeed: $$\left|\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leqslant\frac{|x|^3}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{|y|^3}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant|x|+|y|\to0$$

Comment: @Did Why can I take the absolute value? and How did you get to $|x|+|y|$?

Comment: First question: To show that $x_n\to0$ is equivalent to showing that $|x_n|\to0$ which is equivalent to showing that $|x_n|\leqslant y_n$ with $y_n\to0$. Second question: for example, $$\frac{|x|^3}{x^2+y^2}=|x|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant|x|$$

Comment: Substituting y= alpha *x, we get the limit is 0. But these directional paths togehter cover the space over which paths can be taken.

Comment: @Alephnull "Substituting y= alpha *x, we get the limit is 0. But these directional paths togehter cover the space over which paths can be taken" The argument is (classically) wrong. There exists functions such that $f(x,cx)\to0$ when $x\to0$, for every $c$, and yet $f(x,y)$ does not converge to $0$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Comment: @Did Oh yes I see that now.

Comment: @Alephnull take a look at [Two Path Test for finding limit.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1448015/159845) for an example where lines through the origin all give the same result, yet the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the triangle inequality, we have
$$ |x^3+y^3|\leq |x|^3+|y|^3=|x|x^2+|y|y^2\leq (|x|+|y|)(x^2+y^2) $$
hence
$$ \Big|\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}\Big|\leq |x|+|y|$$
for all $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. Now use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: But what if $(x,y)<0$ am I not "missing" the negative values of the function?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Why am I allowed to take the absolute value? I am changing the function

Comment: The inequality $|\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}|\leq |x|+|y|$ with absolute values implies the inequality $-(|x|+|y|)\leq \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}\leq |x|+|y|$, and now you can use the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to polar coordinates:
$$\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2} \implies \frac{r^3\cos^3t+r^3\sin^3t}{r^2} = r\left(\cos^3t+\sin^3t\right) \stackrel{r \to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0 $$

Comment: This can be made to work, but a step is missing.

Comment: Yes -- this is the missing step.

Comment: Which is why I wrote "missing" and not "invalid".

Comment: And now we have the problem that the sentence "for all $t$, the factor $\left(\cos^3t+\sin^3t\right)$ is bounded" is horribly ambiguous...

Comment: Hm, semantics. I think _a lot steps_ are usually omitted if you want to be _really complete_; but thanks for the comment(s).

Comment: Back to an answer with a missing step...

Comment: I think the point that Did is making that some students do not really understand how to use polar coordinates for instance assume you have gotten $\frac{r}{\sin t} \rightarrow^{r\rightarrow 0} 0$.

Comment: @clark I think so too.